# What are the inhabitants of the [(Type,Type)] kind?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, type-level-computation

On ghci (8.2),

```
:k ('[] :: [(Type,Type)])
```

succeeds, but

```
:k ('[(Bool,Bool)] :: [(Type,Type)])
```

doesn't, since (Bool,Bool) (or even things like ('True,False')) has kind *.

I understand that the problem is with the (,) constructor, that constructs an * Type.

What is the way to represent lists of pairs being strongly typed at type level?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You left out a backtick, `:k ('[ '(Bool,Bool)] :: [(Type,Type)])` works. You need the lifted tuple constructor alongside the lifted list constructor.

Comment: This is correct. It is important to mind the gap between `'[` and `'(...,...)`. Without the additional space the parser sees the character `'['` and gets confused.